# Select from two views and order by both view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two views like:

```
A_team

Jon
joe
kate


B_team

Soabo
david
jim
jake
```

I want to select all the teams from two views and print all in desc.I use

```
select distinct * From A_team 
Union
Select distinct * From B_team
Order by A_team desc;
```

The output is fine. However, the output column name is 'A_team', how to rename the column name in the output please?

UPDATE: using Jiggs's answer then it is solved. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To alias the column you'd do this (assuming your columns are`A_Team` and `B_Team`:

```
select distinct A_team as [MemberName] From A_team 
Union
Select distinct B_team From B_team
Order by [MemberName] desc;
```

Be careful with `union` versus `union all` -- `union` will remove duplicates between the two tables, so if you have "Mary" in both tables, you'll only see "Mary" listed once.  Use `union all` to see it twice if so desired.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an alias name

```
select distinct * From A_team as Team 1
Union
Select distinct * From B_team as Team 2
Order by A_team desc;
```

So your output would be

Team 1

Jon
joe
kate

Team 2

Soabo
david
jim
jake

Comment: You're aliasing the table, not the column.

Comment: You're right ... not having columns in the question threw me off.